# parameter for NSString objects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, parameters, nsarray

I'm writing a function that accepts an NSString objects that are stored in NSArray.   However, I have no idea what kind of parameter must I use in my method declaration. Normally I would use NSString *parameter, but this time I need to use the index number of specified argument. The functions goes like this:

```
NSString * hasCrazy(NSString *stringObjectInsideNSArray[i]) // object from NSArray of NSStrings
{
    if([stringObjectInsideNSArray[i-2] isEqualTo @"crazy"])
    {
        return @"crazy";
    }else
    {
        return @"     ";

    }
}
```

It is absolutely vital for the method, that it checks if stringObjectInsideNSArray[i-2] is equal to @"crazy". Could you guys direct me please?

Comment: So you want to accept an `NSArray` of `NSStrings` as a parameter?

Comment: object of NSArray, which is NSString. hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understand correctly:

```
- (NSString*)hasCrazy:(NSArray*)stringArray index:(int)i {

    //Check that we don't go out of bounds
    if (stringArray.count < 2)
        return  @"     ";


    if ([stringArray[i-2] isEqualToString:@"crazy"])
        return @"crazy";
    else
        return @"     ";
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my stringArray is really huge and with this code I would need to import it many, many times(everytime hasCrazy is called).

Comment: Ah, I miss understood your question, so are you asking to pass in an array and check at i-2 position for "crazy"? Ive updated my answer

Comment: no, I would like to pass in an NSString object which is stored in NSArray. I would pass it in the form stringObject[i].  That NSString object is at position i. What I need, is to get at position i-2 (that is also an NSString object stored in the same NSArray from which the first NSString object originated) and check if it is equal to @"CRAZY35"

Comment: @krompir2 - random's answer does exactly what you asked, given an array and an index it checks if two elements before that index is `@"crazy"`. In Objective-C arrays 9and other objects) are passed by *reference* - the array isn't copied to `hasCrazy` just a reference to the array. It doesn't matter if the array as 5 or 5 million entries the performance is the same. (If you are thinking about Swift, it *claims* to copy arrays but behind these scenes it does its best not to as well.) You probably should read up on objects and references. HTH